# SQL Server stored procedure and jdbc

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, jdbc

I am struggling with SQL Server 2005 and JDBC. I have a stored procedure:

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

ALTER proc [dbo].[sp_logincheck]
    @username as nvarchar(50),
    @password as nvarchar(50)
as
begin
    select * 
    from users 
    where user_name = @username 
      and password = @password 
      and is_active = 'Yes'
end
```

And my `User` class is:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class User {
    private String username;

    private User(String username){
        this.username = username;
    }

    public static User login(String username, char [] password) throws SQLException{
        if(username == null || password == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal arguments passed to method");
        }
        if(login1(username, password)){
            return new User(username);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static boolean login1(String username, char [] password) throws SQLException{
        Connection connection = null;
        CallableStatement statement = null;
        try{
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(AppParameters.dbURL, AppParameters.dbUsername, AppParameters.dbPassword);
        }catch(SQLException e){
            throw e;
        }
        try{
            statement = connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call dbo.sp_logincheck(?,?) }");
            statement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
            statement.setString(2, username);
            statement.setString(3, new String(password));
            statement.execute();
            if(statement.getInt(1) == 1){
                System.out.println("Login Successfull");
                return true;
            }
            System.out.println("Login Failed");
            return false;
        }catch(SQLException sqle){
            sqle.printStackTrace();
            throw sqle;
        }finally{
            try{
                statement.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
            }
            try{
                connection.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
            }
        }
    }

    public  String getUsername(){
        return username;
    }
}
```

Calling `login()` method always prints `Login Failed`. How can I use stored procedure in SQL Server and using JDBC to perform user login? Or going with raw SQL statements is better? Please guide me on this.

**EDIT:**

I would also like to know how to get the `ResultSet` from the above stored procedure, as I have a `select` query inside the stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
if (! rs.isLast()) {
    // match
} else {
    // no match
}
```

Also, I'd recommend to select only the count (`select count(*) as cnt from ...`), and use like `int count = rs.next().getInt("cnt");`

Comment: its working.. but instead of using if(!rs.isLast()), I am using return rs.next(); it will be fine, right?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `select * from users...` in your sql statement to `select count(*) from users...` in the stored procedure .

Otherwise your expression `if(statement.getInt(1) == 1){` does not make any sense.

Comment: I did that, but same output :(

Comment: Have you restarted you application after altering stored procedure?

Comment: Please, add `System.out.println(statement.getInt(1));` after `statement.execute();` and show us what it prints out.

Comment: @Meraman Have you tried `ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();`, and `rs.next()` - if you have rows, the password matches. Also, I'd recommend to select only the count, and use like `int count = rs.getInt("count");`

Comment: @Andremoniy statement.getInt(1) is always returning 0 for valid or invalid users.

Answer (score 0):

If

```
statement.getInt(1)
```

is  equals the number of rows resulted or there are at least one row  . Then this may be a data mismatch case . No data found

Comment: Reading from the statement has no sense, he could get the value he set for the first parameter of the query, it if were int. You can do it even before calling the query, this will surely not contain any result.